# When recompiling a stored procedure are dependency stored procedures also recompiled?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that basically calls 7 or 8 other stored procedures. I'd like know if recompiling the outer stored procedure will cause the 7 or 8 to also be recompiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

[Optimizing SQL Server Stored Procedures to Avoid Recompiles](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/optimizing_sp_recompiles_p1.aspx)

> Stored procedures will normally
>   recompile before execution for a
>   number of reasons, including: dropping
>   and recreating the stored procedure,
>   using the WITH RECOMPILE clause in the
>   CREATE PROCEDURE or the EXECUTE
>   statement, changing the schema of any
>   referenced objects, running the
>   sp_recompile system stored procedure
>   against a table referenced by the
>   stored procedure, restoring the
>   database containing the stored
>   procedure or any object referenced by
>   the stored procedure, or the stored
>   procedures plan dropping from the
>   cache.

About the only automatic way a stored procedure will be recompiled is by adding the [WITH RECOMPILE](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5662581.html)

[here are other ways to recompile a stored procedure](http://www.premier-club.com/tips/Tip/13386)

Comment: sorry, can't vote you up right now because my work has blocked my openid.